# Create a model to classificy a sentence logical or not

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, mxnet

How could I train a model to classify following sentences are logical or illogical?

“He has two legs”–logical
“He has six legs”–illogical

Solution I tried:

1 : Train the classifier by cnn

I have done it before, it works very well if you have enough of data. Problem is I do not have a huge data set which comes with “logical” or “illogical” labels for this case.

2 : Use language model

Train a language model introduced by gluonnlp on some data set like wiki, use it to find out the probability of the sentences. If the probability of the sentences are high, mark it as logical and vice versa. Problem is the results not good.

The way I estimate the probability

```
def __predict(self):
    lines = self.__text_edit_input.toPlainText().split("\n")
    result = ""
    for line in lines:
        result += str(self.__sentence_prob(line, 10)) + "\n"

    self.__text_edit_output.setPlainText(result)

def __prepare_sentence(self, text, max_len):
    result = mx.nd.zeros([max_len, 1], dtype='float32')
    max_len = min(len(text), max_len)
    i = max(max_len - len(text), 0)
    j = 0
    for index in range(i, max_len):
        result[index][0] = self.__vocab[text[j]]
        j = j + 1
    return result

def __sentence_prob(self, text, max_len):
    hiddens = self.__model.begin_state(1, func=mx.nd.zeros, ctx=self.__context)
    tokens = self.__tokenizer(text)
    data = self.__prepare_sentence(tokens, max_len)
    output, _ = self.__model(data, hiddens)
    prob = 0
    for i in range(max_len):
        total_prob = mx.nd.softmax(output[i][0])
        prob += total_prob[self.__vocab[i]].asscalar()

    return prob / max_len
```

Possible issues of language models:

```
1. Do not use correct way to split the sentences(I am using jieba to split the Chinese senteces)
2. Number of vocab is too small/big(test 10000, 15000 and 30000)
3. Loss too high(ppl around 190) after 50 epochs?
4. Number of sentences length should be larger/smaller(tried 10,20,35)
5. The data I use do not meet my requirements(not every sentences are logical) 
6. Language model is not appropriate for this task?
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 6. Language model is not appropriate for this task?** is the main problem. Language models are built to make sense of the input text with respect of language usage (syntax, semantics etc.) and not draw logical conclusions. So, you may not get good results even with a large amount of data or very deep models.
The problem you're trying to solve is **extremely** difficult. Something you may want to look at is [Symbolic AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence). There's a lot of [ongoing research](https://skymind.ai/wiki/symbolic-reasoning) in this area.